# Where I can find documentation for ASP.NET Identity RC1?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

After Microsoft updated ASP.NET Identity framework to version 1.0.0-rc1, I can't find any documentation or guide how to use it. There is 2 sample projects on github ([one](https://github.com/onybo/Asp.Net-Identity-RC1-sample-app), [two](https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample/)), but they not covering advanced things like tokens, password reset, roles, etc.

Answer (score 1):

i believe the only real documentation is replies on this forum. The structure of several entities have changed since the beta as well.

I also could do with some more in depth information, particularly

- linking to your own custom user table
- having access to this custom table from the controller's User property
- access to the user and roles from a authorise attribute regardless of the actual login method (local,gmail,twitter etc)

Answer (score 1):

I have added a project called WebCustomUser to https://github.com/onybo/Asp.Net-Identity-RC1-sample-app/tree/master/WebApplication.

This project demonstrates use of the methods:

- RequireTokenConfirmationForSignInAsync
- ConfirmSignInTokenAsync

to implement token activation of user accounts.

Update: 
The project now include a custom entity framework model with custom users which have an email address added (just as an example).

The modeling project that contains two diagrams that shows some of the new classes in ASP.NET identity is now in a separate solution so that the main solution can be opened in the profession SKU.

Heres the modified Register action and the Activate action.

```
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            // Create a profile, password, and link the local login before signing in the user
            User user = new User(model.UserName);
            var result = await new UserManager(IdentityManager).CreateLocalUserAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Success)
            {
                var token = Guid.NewGuid();
                var tokenResult = await AuthenticationManager.RequireTokenConfirmationForSignInAsync(token.ToString(), user.Id, DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
                if (tokenResult.Success)
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("Registered", "Account", new { userId = user.Id.ToString(), token = token.ToString() });
                }
                else
                    AddModelError(tokenResult, "RequireTokenConfirmation failed");
            }
            else
            {
                AddModelError(result, "Failed to register user name: " + model.UserName);
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Activate(string userId, string token)
    {
        var tokenResult = await AuthenticationManager.ConfirmSignInTokenAsync(token);
        return RedirectToAction("Login", new {returnUrl="/home"});
    }
```

Comment: Btw, this solution only can be opened in Ultimate edition of Visual Studio. I have Professional Edition installed, so no luck for me. Will upgrade VS2013 Preview to Ultimate.

Answer (score 0):

You can find samples to the nightly build of the identity library [here](https://github.com/rustd/AspnetIdentitySample).